# List initialization with other list. Will objects be copied or referenced?

Tags: c#, collections

Hi I have a list with Person class as follows

```
public class person
{
    public int age;
    public string name;
}
```

I am trying to do the following.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<person> person1 = new List<person>();
    person1.Add(new person { age = 10, name = "P1" });
    person1.Add(new person { age = 11, name = "Q1" });
    person1.Add(new person { age = 12, name = "R1" });

    List<person> person2 = new List<person>(person1);
    person2[0].name = "P2";
    Console.WriteLine("---------Person1---------");

    foreach (person P in person1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Age=" + P.age);
        Console.WriteLine("Name=" + P.name);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("---------Person2---------");
    foreach (person P in person2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Age=" + P.age);
        Console.WriteLine("Name=" + P.name);
    }
}
```

The Output is that the value of first object in both the lists is changed to P2 while I expect to change it only in `person2` list. I thought the list items would be copied into `person2` list.
MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx) says that the elements are copied to the new list which is not happening in above case. what am I missing here?

Comment: The elements will be copied, which means with objects that their references are copied. No new objects are created. This is a bit misleading wording in MSDN, better leave a comment there so they could clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you're making here is with reference variables. What's held in the list are references to objects of type `person`. When you copy the list, it only copies the references to these objects, so each list contains references to exactly the same set of objects.

For a more in depth example of what I'm talking about, consider the following code:

```
person me = new person { age = 20, name = "Lauraducky" };
person you = me;
you.name = "Programmerzzz";
Console.WriteLine(me.name); // Outputs Programmerzzz
```

This is essentially what you're doing in your example. The `me` variable doesn't get copied, a reference to it just gets passed to the `you` variable. Then the object at that reference location is changed. The key here being that both variables point to the same location.

If you want to make a deep copy of the list, you'll have to do so manually. For example:

```
List<person> person2 = new List<person>();
foreach (person p in person1) {
    person2.Add(new person { age = p.age, name = p.name });
}
```

For more reading about reference types, see [this excellent explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5057284/8718143).

Answer (score 0):

Class is copy by reference, struct is copy by value.

So you change the people's value , you will link to a original reference.

```
public Struct person
{
    public int age;
    public string name;
}
```

And if you use struct, try again, you will see different

Comment: Using structs for everything isn't particularly good advice as objects get larger and more cumbersome. Structs have a very specific use case. I think it's much better to learn to work with classes and take the benefits of passing things by reference.

Comment: Yes , I can't agree with you anymore , copy by value usually use more performance.

Answer (score 0):

You're copying by reference and not by value. First thing to do is fix your class. So you can create 'person' objects using a constructor. The code below creates a new object rather than copying the reference of the former list.

```
public static void Main()
{

    Console.WriteLine("Program Started!");

    List<person> person1 = new List<person>();
    person1.Add(new person(10, "P1" ));
    person1.Add(new person( 11, "Q1" ));
    person1.Add(new person(12,  "R1" ));

    List<person> person2 = new List<person>();
    foreach(person p in person1)
    {
        person2.Add(new person(p)); //WE COPY BY VALUE. BY ALLOCATING SPACE FOR A NEW OBJECT.
    }

    person2[0].name = "P2";
    Console.WriteLine("---------Person1---------");

    foreach (person P in person1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Age=" + P.age);
        Console.WriteLine("Name=" + P.name);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("---------Person2---------");
    foreach (person P in person2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Age=" + P.age);
        Console.WriteLine("Name=" + P.name);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Program Ended!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public class person
{
    public int age;
    public string name;

    public person(person p) {
        this.age = p.age;
        this.name = p.name;
    }

    public person(int _age, string _name)
    {
        this.age = _age;
        this.name = _name;
    }

}
```